# « Il y a de vieux sweats dans l'armoire, et je les recyclerai quand j'en aurai le temps. »

Tags: pronoms, en

I came across this sentence and got confused. What is the pronoun *en* doing here? I thought it probably refers to the word *temps*. But *temps* is already there in the sentence, so is *en* redundant? Is this a grammatical mistake?

Comment: *En* would have referred to *temps* in: *Je les recyclerai quand j'en aurai, du temps*, but that implies time would already have been mentioned.

Comment: Honestly it's just a fancier, more formal way of saying "quand j'aurai le temps". You see it more in written texts, it's a common pattern: "J'enleverai les petites roues lorsque j'en serai capable."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"En"» does not refer to "temps" but to the action expressed by the verb "recycler".

There are several ways to use a replacement for « en », and some do not result in a good style.

- Il y a de vieux sweats dans l'armoire, et je les recyclerai quand j'aurai le temps **de le faire**.
- Il y a de vieux sweats dans l'armoire, et je les recyclerai quand j'aurai le temps **de les recycler**. (*not too good in reason of the repetition*)
- Il y a de vieux sweats dans l'armoire, et je les recyclerai quand j'aurai le temps **de faire leur recyclage**. (*not too good*)

You can, however, do away with "en", but the sentence does not mean exactly  the same thing, although, in most cases the difference doesn't matter.

- Il y a de vieux sweats dans l'armoire, et je les recyclerai quand j'aurai le temps. »

Comment: @Lambie What else could it be? what do you have in mind?

Comment: @Lambie The antecedent can't be scattered over two clauses, and in fact it must be out of "quand j'en aurais le temps". According to your understanding, on top of that, you end up with twice the expression involving "temps" in the sentence where the replacement is made: "je les recyclerai quand j'en aurai le temps"  → (rough replacement)  "je les recyclerai quand j'[**avoir le temps de recycler]** aurai le temps" . It can't be that, can't you see?

Comment: @Lambie *Je les recyclerai quand j'aurai le temps d'avoir le temps de les recycler...*

Comment: @Lambie This correction changes piddling little to the nonsense.

Comment: @Lambie I don't believe so, the addition of the pronoun "les" changes nothing to the awful redundancy your antecedent causes. Have you tried to construct the sentence using _your_ replacement in full? Do that and let's see what you come up with. Can it be different from what another comment shows? Impossible…

Comment: About your stylistic remark in the answer, I wouldn't be worried about the fact that replacing the pronoun doesn't result in good style, because that's the purpose of a pronoun in the first place! :)

Comment: @Gae.S. I don't get your meaning. Couldn't someone who is not too familiar with the French language think of using a long form instead? These long forms are still grammatically correct.